# Entity Framework "Edit" ActionResult which keeps or uploads new html file input originaly posted and saved through the "Create" ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, file, input

I have a MVC 5 controller with views, using Entity Framework project.

I have a controller and view for my Item Model:

```
public partial class Item
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
}
```

I changed the Entity Framework `Create` view and controller to post an html file input and save the file path as the `ImageURL`

A snippet from the view looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
        <div class="form-group">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Upload a file</legend>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

The controller's Create ActionResult looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ItemID,ImageURL")] Item item, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    item.ImageURL = "/Uploads/" + file.FileName;
                    db.Items.Add(item);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                }
                ViewBag.Message = "Upload successful";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Upload failed";
                ViewBag.ItemTypeID = new SelectList(db.ItemTypes, "ItemTypeID", "ItemType1", item.ItemTypeID);
                return View(item);
            }
        }
```

As you can see I use `var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);` and `item.ImageURL = "/Uploads/" + file.FileName;` To populate my `ImageUrl`. The file itself is saved on the server.

Now my issue is that I don't know how to get the "Edit" view and ActionResult to allow me either to keep the same image or upload a new image.

How can I do this?

What I have done so far is in the Edit view to write:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @if (Model.ImageURL == null)
    {
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Upload a file</legend>
            <div class="editor-field">
               @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }

    else
    {
        /*Keep or upload new image here*/
    }
</div>
```

What would I need to write in that `else {...}` and what would I need to write in the controller's  `public ActionResult Edit(int? id) {...}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just show Image in the img control and below that use another file control , in case user need to change the uploaded image..

```
<div class="form-group">
@if (Model.ImageURL == null)
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload a file</legend>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}

else
{
    /*show Image  in an img control using image path*/
    <img src="@Model.ImageURL" height="100" width="100" />
    <fieldset>
        <legend>change the file</legend>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

and at Action part everything will be same , remove the old file and save new one and update db as well.
also Don't forget to use form as you have used in the create view.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: Thank you this is the correct answer. I need also to allow for null if a file is not uploaded on the edit post.

Comment: if (Request.Files.Count > 0)  You can check if files count is greater than zero or not..

Answer (score 0):

if image is not uploaded For the particular item How you will edit . You can do create and edit both in single action method by

```
  var itemInDb = db.items
                .Where(c => c.itemid== id) // or whatever your key is
                .SingleOrDefault();
            if (itemInDb != null)
                db.Countries.ApplyCurrentValues(item);
            else
                db.Countries.AddObject(item);
  db.SaveChanges();
```

if multiple images are  there for single image you can loop it